# How to add a pay until date to invoice in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, model, invoice, plugin, crud

Please excuse me if I am asking a dumb question, but I am new to Magento and frankly, my first impression is that it is over-designed and poorly documented. Maybe this is part of their business model, or maybe I am missing something. I hope I am missing something!

In my country, every invoice has to mention the date when was created and a date by which the client has to make the payment. The fact that (from what I can tell) Magento doesn't automatically generate an invoice for each order placed, tells me that these dates should be attributes of the invoice, and not attributes of the order.

I have made a plugin using the following code:

**app/code/ideologic/RoInvoice/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice" type="ideologic\RoInvoice\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice" />
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice">
        <plugin sortOrder="1" name="setDueDate" type="ideologic\RoInvoice\Model\Order\Invoice" />
    </type>
</config>
```

**app/code/ideologic/RoInvoice/Model/Order/Invoice.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © SC ideologic SRL, All rights reserved.
 */
namespace ideologic\RoInvoice\Model\Order;

class Invoice
{

    public function beforeSetCreatedAt(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice $invoice, $createdAt){
        $invoice->addData(array('DueDateDelay'=>15));
        return $createdAt;
    }

}
```

But for some reason the **addData()** function call **has no effect**. When I am calling getData() from app/code/ideologic/RoInvoice/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php I am getting a null value (or empty string).

From what I have read, I have to load the 'Model' before calling setData(). How do I do that? Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't directly answer your question but is a solution to one of your issues.

Certain payment methods wont invoice automatically. They need manual attention.

I put together this externsion to automatically invoices orders based on certain conditions.

https://github.com/DominicWatts/AutoInvoice

So solves that part

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I still want to add that that second date as an attribute of the invoice, and somehow, adding it to the order object seems wrong...

Comment: Have you been able to add column to sales_order table or sales_invoice table yet? Doesn't really matter which. Just need to make sure you update the new date column in either table after invoice generation . Will be easier to work with updating order. Do you want to use event like checkout success or run something on schedule?

Comment: I have managed to add the column in sales_invoice table. And I have a plugin beforeSetCreatedAt() in invoice in which I wish to set that attribute. But if i don't call $this->save(), the table column contains only NULL values, and if I do call $this->save(), it enters some kind of infinite loop, eating up all the memory.

Comment: I could try to use an event instead of a plugin. But which one is triggered when the invoice is generated? I care more about the invoice than about the order, because the PayUntil date should be X days after the invoice was generated, not after the order was placed. I guess in some cases, could be a delay between the order placement and the invoice creation. I wouldn't want to auto-create the invoice, because the seller might have to check the product availability first.